# How to use Codeship's project SSH key in step file

Tags: .net-core, continuous-deployment, codeship

In the CodeShip Pro documentation, the recommendation for doing Continuous Deployment to Digital Ocean involves encrypting an SSH private key, and storing that in your repository. To do this, you need to install `jet` on your machine. Unfortunately, `jet` is not available on my platform (Win 10 64-bit).

In every CodeShip project, there's an SSH key generated by CodeShip, and controlled by them. The documentation doesn't describe how to use that SSH key in a CodeShip Pro setup. Is there a way to do so? Or is it only available in CodeShip Basic projects?

I'm trying to get a .NET Core 1.1 project built, copied, and deployed, with external system package dependencies. The commands involved include a big pile of `apt-get` work for setup, `dotnet restore`, `dotnet build`, maybe a `dotnet publish`, and an `scp` step for the deploy itself.